# Add values from TextBox in Useform to a predefined table

Tags: excel, vba

The following code is in the userform, and is called when i click a button.
I want to submit the text from 7 TextBoxes in my UserForm to a predefined tabel in my worksheet (also 7 columns in the table). The tabel is named "Tabell1". The "Ny_____Input" are the names of the textboxes.

I get an errorcode Run-time error 91.

```
Private Sub LeggTilKontakt1()


Dim Tbl As ListObject

Set Tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tabell1")

With Tbl
    .DataBodyRange(2, 1).Value = Me.NyNavnInput.Text
    .DataBodyRange(2, 2).Value = Me.NyFirmaInput.Text
    .DataBodyRange(2, 3).Value = Me.NyTelefonInput.Text
    .DataBodyRange(2, 4).Value = Me.NyEpostInput.Text
    .DataBodyRange(2, 5).Value = Me.NyRolle1Input.Value
    .DataBodyRange(2, 6).Value = Me.NyRolle2Input.Value
    .DataBodyRange(2, 7).Value = Me.NyRolle3Input.Value
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: How did you add the tabell1?  that error is due to an object not being set.  Perhaps the set Tbl command is failing as it cannot find that listobject in the active sheet?

Comment: The table was added to the worksheet with "insert table" from the ribbon.

Comment: You will get that error if the 1st row of your tbale is empty

Comment: Corrected spelling mistake with missing s in ListObjects. Still get error Run-time 91 on the top line .DataBodyRange <...>

Comment: See my last comment

Answer (score 0):

adding 
    `.ListRows.Add (1)` and changing `.DataBodyRange(2, x)` to `.DataBodyRange(1, x)`
solved the issue. Thanks!